# I have a business Directory website - need url redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have joomla website with business directory, my urls are formed like

http://odishayellowpages.in/item/business-name

I want to remove the part item and still be able to access the page. how can I do it.

I have tried in .htacess -

```
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,item].
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: You can create a subdomain on your ISP to point to this directory?